# Ionic 2: Removing login page from navigation stack, causes nav.push cease to work in Dashboard page

Tags: ionic2

I am having this weird issue. When user logs in, user is forwarded to dashboard. But before this I remove login page from navigation stack so that when user
presses hardware back button they are not taken back to login page (as they're already logged in).

Following is my  login method of login page

```
loginUser(){
    this.loading=this.loadingctrl.create({
            content:"Logging in, please wait..."
     });

     this.loading.present();

     this.ajaxRequest = this.webservice.loginUser(params).subscribe(data => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        if(data.status =="ok"){
            this.navctrl.push(DashboardPage).then(()=>{
                const index = this.viewCtrl.index;
                this.navctrl.remove(index);
                //Above two lines finds index of current page and removes current page, i.e. login page from navigation stack
            });
        }else{
            //show error alert
        }
     }, err =>{
        this.loading.dismiss();
     });

}
```

This code works well but however encountered a weird issue

**PROBLEM**

Any button in dashboard, or in swipe menu doesn't work.
Each link/buttons calls some method which navigates to some other page. Example method -

```
gotoProductsPage(){
 console.log("method gotoProductsPage is called");
 this.navCtrl.push(ProductsPage);
}
```

I can see the methods are being called because i can see log being printed in console. The only thing is `this.navCtrl.push(ProductsPage);`seems to be not working.

I did further test and commented the lines  `const index = this.viewCtrl.index;` and `this.navctrl.remove(index);` in login method of login page. 
Now all the button works. But hardware back button takes user back to login page.
Can anybody enlighten me why my app is having this weird behavior?? 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do `this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to manipulate the Navigation Stack by trying to get LoginPage index and removing it.
I suggest simply setting the `DashboardPage` as the root of the navigation stack.

```
if(data.status =="ok"){
            this.navctrl.setRoot(DashboardPage).then(()=>{
                console.log("done");
            });
}else{
            //show error alert
}
```

Now it will not navigate to login page on `back`.

Comment: My silly mistake, how could I overlook this. Thanks!